# First item of Recyclerview duplicate twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm trying to display images from a particular folder (3 images) and store them in `Recyclerview` using code below , But the first item of  `Recyclerview` repeated twice ,appears in the first and last item and the last item not showing like the picture below :

[image]

**MyAdapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    Context c;
    ImageView img;
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
        this.c = c;
        this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.picture_item, parent, false);
        img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cat_imageView);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Spacecraft s = spacecrafts.get(position);
        Glide.with(c).load(s.getUri()).into(img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return spacecrafts.size();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        /**/
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rc);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(WallpaperAutoChanger.this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, getData()));
       /**/
}
}
  private ArrayList<Spacecraft> getData() {
        ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts = new ArrayList<>();
        File downloadsFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/wallpapers");
        Spacecraft s;
        if (downloadsFolder.exists()) {
            File[] files = downloadsFolder.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                s = new Spacecraft();
                s.setName(file.getName());
                s.setUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
                spacecrafts.add(s);
            }
        }
        return spacecrafts;
    }
```

can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check your list. Is it returning what the RecyclerView is showing?

Comment: @TheWanderer yeah i checked it with toast and i'm sure list contains the 3 URIs of images

Comment: Don't put `img` as a global variable. You can get your ImageView in `onBindViewHolder()` by using `holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_imageView)`.

Comment: @TheWanderer thank you so much it's work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `img` to a local variable. It shouldn't be global. You can move its initialization into `onBindViewHolder()` like so:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_imageView);
```

Then just call it where you're using it.

I'm not entirely sure since I haven't looked at the source code, but I don't believe there's any guarantee that `onBindViewHolder` is called for index 0 before `onCreateViewHolder` is called for index 1 (they're not sequential), meaning your `img` variable was just using the wrong assignment.